# Filter point cloud based on proximity to another point cloud

Tags: geometry-nodes, point-clouds

I'm trying to build a nature scene with geometry nodes, and I want to make sure that plants aren't exactly on top of each other. For example, I don't want grass growing inside of trees and sticking out of the roots.

The way I thought about going about this is to make a point cloud for the most important objects first, then when I make subsequent clouds, they can be filtered out based on the proximity to the original cloud. How would I go about this?

Comment: Are you using particule systems ?

Comment: No. I'm using point clouds in geometry nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a solution:

[image]

After converting the point cloud of the trees to geometry with `Points to Vertices`, I simply use the node `Geometry Proximity` to check if the grass is at a certain distance from these points, and use that as a selection when instantiating.

[image]

Comment: I think that's perfect! I'll try it out next chance I get! Trying to get the boolean field from distance to points was what I was trying to do before, but I didn't think to use the route you did.